# Why does the superposition principle work?

Tags: electromagnetism, superposition

I am reading Feynman volume 2. (I was reading Griffiths at first.) I don't really understand why the superposition principle of electrical forces (or fields) works. Is there anything deeper in that?

Griffiths said: *"That's an experimental fact."* By reading Feynman I have a feeling that there may be something deeper?

Comment: What did you read in Feynman that implies something deeper? The superposition principle is simply another expression for the linearity of the field equations. That linearity holds to very high field strength before it is broken by the non-linear terms in QED. We are just beginning to explore this non-linearity in high energy physics experiments.

Comment: Sorry if the question doesnt make much sense.i thought there must be something deeper in that.
by the way Feynman said,'ideas of field lines donot contain the deepest principle of electrodynamics ,which is superposition principle..
i think i need to read that again..

Comment: I don't know about that. Classical electrodynamics is completely linear and QED is non-linear, but experimentally one has to work really hard to get into the non-linear regime. So unless you are one of the few people on Earth who are working on gamma-gamma colliders I wouldn't spend too much thought on non-linearity in electrodynamics.

Answer (score 2):

Do you understand electric fields themselves? And the resulting force that charges experience in such a field?

In that case expanding that understanding to superposition is simply to look at another analogy. When two people A and B pull in a block, the resulting force $F_r$ on the object is just found by adding the force vectors $F_A$ and $F_B$. The *two forces* $F_A$ and $F_B$ together and that one resulting force $F_r$ give same result. That is superposition; to express one force as other smaller force vectors that might be more appropriate for the present coordinate system or of some other mathematical reason, without changing the actual resulting force on the object.

Comment: Griffits is Right. It's as it is as you said too.

Comment: @P.A.M Indeed. "It is as it is"-answers are rarely encouraging, though :)

Comment: Am I wrong?! ;)